# Can't pass proper value in form, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**I have created a form in react using [Formiz](https://formiz-react.com/). But it's not sending right value.**

Here is a working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/formiz-pricing-wizard-forked-fcnsn?file=/src/fields/fieldradio.js

Currently it is sending me this value:

[image: wrong value]

But it should send me this value:

[image: right value]

I already tried changing step1.js from this:

```
const transformOptions = (options) =>
  options.map(({ subCategory, price, radioImage }, i) => ({
    label: <span>{subCategory}</span>,
    id: `${subCategory}-${i}`,
    value: `${price}`,
    image: radioImage
  }));
```

To this:

```
const transformOptions = (options) =>
  options.map(({ subCategory, price, radioImage }, i) => ({
    label: <span>{subCategory}</span>,
    id: `${subCategory}-${i}`,
    value: `${subCategory} - ${price}`,
    image: radioImage
  }));
```

It sends me the right values but `totalPrice` function in MyForm.js stops working:

```
const totalPrice = React.useMemo(() => {
    return categories.reduce(
      (total, c) =>
        total + (myForm.values[c] ? parseInt(myForm.values[c], 10) : 0),
      0
    );
  }, [myForm.values]);
```

***Will anyone please help me to fix it? Because I've been trying to find a solution for hours but still couldn't find one and can't wrap my head around what's going wrong!***

Comment: Just tested your `totalPrice` and it works correctly. It updates the input in step1.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito it doesn't work when I change step1.js to this `value: `${subCategory} - ${price}`,`

Comment: Your question (and the accepted answer) both use `useMemo` incorrectly. `myForm.values` is a compound value. JavaScript treats `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3]` as different even though they contain the same values. If you add a `console.log` inside the memo you will see that the cache is almost never used for your component. The result is additional complexity, memory leak, and little-to-no optimization.

Comment: @Mulan Thanks for pointing that out. I never realized that could create so much problem. Can you please give me an example for how to use it correctly?

Comment: the number of combinations for possible values of `myForm.values` is so large that you are not actually benefiting from the memo. in this case just remove it. you can sum thousands of elements in just a few milliseconds so i wouldn't bother trying to micro-optimize here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you modified `value` from `${price}` to `${subCategory} - ${price}` now your `totalPrice` is broken because in `myForm.values[c]` there is no more just the price but the subCategory also.

To solve this it's just necessary fix your `totalPrice` in this way:

```
  const totalPrice = React.useMemo(() => {

    return categories.reduce(
      (total, c) =>
        total +
        (myForm.values[c]?.split("-")[1]
          ? parseInt(myForm.values[c]?.split("-")[1], 10)
          : 0),
      0
    );
  }, [myForm.values]);
```

I replaced `myForm.values[c]` with `myForm.values[c]?.split("-")[1]` in order to "clean" `value` from `subCategory` part and leave just `price`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formiz-pricing-wizard-forked-0q6yfm?file=/src/MyForm.js) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: Happy to ear that =) . Have a nice coding!